# C++ - Class method changes member variable, but not in main

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I have a Student class which stores a student's name and registration number. One of the private members of the Student class is a map which stores a student's module code (string), along with the mark for the module (float).

The class has an 'addMark' function which takes a module code and the mark for that module. If the module already exists in the map, the mark is overwritten. Otherwise, it is inserted into the map.

```
void Student::addMark(const string &module, float mark)
{
    map<string, float>::iterator iter = marks.find(module);
    if (iter != marks.end()){marks[module] = mark;}
    else{marks.insert({module, mark});}
}
```

I have checked, and this seems to work inside that function.

In the main function, I have a vector markLine which stores each token of a line in a text file containing the marks. The first token (markLine.at(0)) is the registration number, the second token is the module code, and the third token is the mark. So the vector might look like the following for a line:

```
markLine = {10105, "CE101", 78.5};
```

Anyway, after reading a line and storing each token, the module mark needs to be stored for the correct student, so I use a for loop to go through all the students and see if their registration number matches. If it does, the mark is added:

```
for (Student st: studVect)
{
    if (st.getRegNo() == markLine.at(0))
    {
        st.addMark(markLine.at(1), markLine.at(2));
    }
}
```

But when I check afterwards to see if the marks have changed for a student, they have not.

I've googled around a lot and found some questions quite similar to mine, and I have a feeling that this is something to do with references, and a copy of marks being created. However, I'm not really sure *where* exactly I need to be using a reference. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Comment: `for (Student st: studVect)` creates a *copy* of each `Student` while iterating. change to `for (Student& st: studVect)`

Comment: Oh gosh, I had a feeling it was something so obvious. Thank you!

Comment: Also, in `addMark` why would you use a iterator for the mark instead of just setting it?  `marks[module] = mark;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with a copy of the Student record.

Change

```
for (Student st: studVect)
```

to

```
for (Student &st: studVect)
```